# Rename column by position pandas

Tags: pandas, replace

I am trying to rename a column by position in a pandas dataframe.

I tried:

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: "Line Items" }, inplace=True) #replace name
```

But this code replaces all columns which has have the same name as column[0] with "Line Items" irrespective of their positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us convert to `series` then change the value by `.iloc` and assign it back

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
s.iloc[0] = 'something'
df.columns = s
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the columns in a list comprehension with basic logic

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AABCDA'))

df.columns = ["Line Items" if i == 0 else x for i,x in enumerate(df.columns)]

print(df)
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [Line Items, A, B, C, D, A]
#Index: []
```

Comment: Happy holiday~~

Comment: Thanks. Happy holiday!